# How to Pass from value to DataTable in onClick button?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have two buttons, when clicked, they will send 0001 or 0002 respectively

[image]

I try to receive value from oSearch

It succeeds, but only shows the value of the first click

For example:

I click the first button first, and 0001 will appear in the search bar. After closing the window, click the second button, and 0001 will appear in the search bar instead of 0002.

If I click the second button first, 0002 will appear in the search bar. After closing the window, click the first button, and 0002 will appear in the search bar instead of 0001.

It cannot display the corresponding value according to the button I clicked

getvalue is what I use to get the value passed by the button

How can I adjust it so that I can click which button so that the corresponding value will appear in the search bar?

Thanks for your help

```
jBPM('#modal-table').DataTable({
    "retrieve": true, 
    "searching": true, 
    "paging": false, 
    "ordering": true, 
    //"destroy": true, 
    "columnDefs":[
    {
        "targets":[2],
        "searchable":false
    }
    ],
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": getvalue}
});
```

Comment: could you share the full code? did you try to use ```trigger event``` when you click the buttons?

Comment: I think you can load the datatable first when click button and set value 0001 or 0002 in input (when click button) and use the ```trigger``` function for search. How about my suggestion.

Comment: I modified it according to your suggestion and completed it successfully, thank you

Comment: Could you upvote to my comment if you are satisfied?